# Proving a Function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

> Consider the function $f\colon[0,+\infty)\to X$ where $f(x) = 3\sqrt{x+5}-1$.
>
> (a) Determine a set $X$ for which $f$ is onto, and then prove that $f$ is onto using your $X$.

Really stuck and no idea how to proceed. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Below is my attempt at the solution, please critique it if possible. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Hint: $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Do you know what it means for $f$ to be onto some set? That would seem to be the place to start.

Comment: I know the definition of surjective ... just having trouble finding the co-domain that would make f surke

Comment: I know f is increasing, it's lowest value is -1 --> that much i know

Comment: The lowest value of $f$ may be $-1$, but *not on the domain you are given*.  Remember that $x$ must be in the domain $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: @mweiss Thank, i figured out the lower value $3sqrt{5} -1$

Comment: any thoughts ... how's my solution looking? ... is it readable?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know that the smallest value that $f$ can take is $-1$, you now need to ask yourself three questions

- What happens if we include numbers smaller than $-1$ in $X$? What happens if we include $-1$ in $X$?
- Is there a largest value that $f$ can take? If so, what is it, and what happens if we include larger numbers in $X$?
- Are there any intermediate values (i.e. between the smallest and largest) at which $f$ behaves strangely? If so, what are they, and how does that change $X$?

If you can answer the first two questions, then you should be able to make a good guess as to what $X$ should be. If you can answer all of them, then you understand the concept very well and may just need help with mechanical details.

Comment: Before I read the above answer, I was able to formula what $X$ ought to be. Now would I need to show that $f(x) =y$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We have for $x \geq 0$, $f(x) = 3\sqrt{x+5} - 1 \geq 3\sqrt{5} - 1$. Thus this gives the range of $f$: $[3\sqrt{5} - 1, +\infty) = X$. To show $f$ onto, take $\alpha \in X$, then write $\alpha = 3\sqrt{5} - 1 + r$, with $r \geq 0$. We need to show the equation:

$3\sqrt{x+5} - 1 = 3\sqrt{5} - 1 + r$ has a solution $x \in [0, +\infty)$. This means:

$\sqrt{x+5} = \dfrac{3\sqrt{5} + r}{3} = \sqrt{5} + \dfrac{r}{3}$, and square both sides:

$x + 5 = 5 + \dfrac{2\sqrt{5}r}{3} + \dfrac{r^2}{9}$. So:

$x = \dfrac{2\sqrt{5}r}{3} + \dfrac{r^2}{9} \geq 0$.

This proves $f$ onto.